# Sql update makes datagridview disappear

Tags: c#, sql, .net

```
 private void wypelnijTabeleDanymi3(string pytanie3)
    {
        using (connection = new SqlConnection(string_polaczeniowy))
        {
            connection.Open();
            SqlCommand xquery = new SqlCommand(pytanie3, connection);
            xquery.Parameters.AddWithValue("@imie", txtImie.Text);
            xquery.Parameters.AddWithValue("@nazwisko", txtNazwisko.Text);
            xquery.Parameters.AddWithValue("@danekontaktowe", rtbDaneKontaktowe.Text);
            xquery.Parameters.AddWithValue("@idOsoby", tbIdOsoby.Text);
            SqlDataAdapter xdata = new SqlDataAdapter(xquery);
            dtsTabelaTestowa.Clear();
            xdata.Fill(dtsTabelaTestowa);
            dgTabelaTestowa.DataSource = dtsTabelaTestowa.Tables[0];
            dgTabelaTestowa.Refresh();
        }
    }

  private void btnUpdate_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string wartosc = "UPDATE tblStudent17 SET Imie = @imie, Nazwisko = @nazwisko, Dane_Kontaktowe = @danekontaktowe WHERE idOsoby= @idOsoby";
            wypelnijTabeleDanymi3(wartosc);
        }
```

Can somebody tell me why this code makes sql datagridview disappear when I click 'update button"? The code fill textboxes with data when I click a row in datagridview, then I can write new value in particular texbox then click btnUpdate and whole sql datagridview disappears BUT the new value is properly changed if I check it manually. I'd like it to refresh datagridview instantly when I click btnUpdate. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: It looks to me as though you're trying to fill a data table with an `UPDATE` statement? Is that right?

Comment: Hmm looks like it. Should I add another sqlcommand with "select * from tblStudent17" under parameters?

Comment: @Mike I would say do the update first and then make a separate select. in case there is an exception you know which line its from

Comment: @LasseVågsætherKarlsen Yes I fill a data table using UPDATE statement, I download cells' values to proper textboxes and then I want to change particular value using proper textbox, click Enter and have that value refreshed in datagridview. Changing the value works ok but I can't get datagridview to refresh properly.

Comment: Well, an `UPDATE` statement by itself doesn't return any data at all, so that's why your data table ends up being empty. You can coax an `UPDATE` statement into returning data but then it will return the data it updated, not the whole table. You should separate the act of updating the table in the database from the act of updating your datatable/gridview with data from the database.

Comment: this sounds like a PostBack Issue at first glance.. what are you doing in your `Page_Load` event?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 private void btnUpdate_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string wartosc = "UPDATE tblStudent17 SET Imie = @imie, Nazwisko = @nazwisko, Dane_Kontaktowe = @danekontaktowe WHERE idOsoby= @idOsoby";
            using (connection = new SqlConnection(string_polaczeniowy))
            {
                connection.Open();
                SqlCommand xquery = new SqlCommand(wartosc, connection);
                xquery.Parameters.AddWithValue("@imie", txtImie.Text);
                xquery.Parameters.AddWithValue("@nazwisko", txtNazwisko.Text);
                xquery.Parameters.AddWithValue("@danekontaktowe", rtbDaneKontaktowe.Text);
                xquery.Parameters.AddWithValue("@idOsoby", tbIdOsoby.Text);
                SqlDataAdapter xdata = new SqlDataAdapter(xquery);
                xdata.Fill(dtsTabelaTestowa);
            }

            wypelnijTabeleDanymi();
        }


 private void wypelnijTabeleDanymi()
        {
            using (connection = new SqlConnection(string_polaczeniowy))
            {
                connection.Open();
                SqlCommand xquery = new SqlCommand("select * from tblStudent17", connection);
                SqlDataAdapter xdata = new SqlDataAdapter(xquery);
                dtsTabelaTestowa.Clear();
                xdata.Fill(dtsTabelaTestowa);
                dgTabelaTestowa.DataSource = dtsTabelaTestowa.Tables[0];
                dgTabelaTestowa.Refresh();

            }
        }
```

Works great like this. Thanks for the help, appreciate it.